# Sql server 2000 replication error

Tags: sql-server

Good morning,

I have a sql server 2000 machine, with SP4.

I have a transactional replication.

A keep receving this error message:

The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'servername'

the logreader stops responding.When i click start it starts fine, and the replication starts fine.And then, works for hours, and the problem comes back.

In the begining i though it could be timeouts, but i already set a couple of parameters in the logreader profile,like querytimeout/readbatchsize.

Sometimes when the logreader stops,it generates a dump, but not always.

In event viewer,  it appears this message:

17066 :
SQL Server Assertion: File: , line=1985
Failed Assertion = 'startLSN >= m_curLSN'.

18052 :
Error: 3624, Severity: 20, State: 1.

17066 :
SQL Server Assertion: File: , line=2223
Failed Assertion = 'm_noOfScAlloc == 0'.

I also executed checkdb in the databases, and they are fine.

have you every experienced something similar?

thanks in advance,

Renato Alves.

Comment: Have run a DBCC CHECKDB on the database in question?  Also, have you looked in the system event log for any reported hardware errors?

Comment: Got in a hurry... "Have you run..."

Comment: I have executed checkdb in all database, and every thing is fine.No signs of hardware problem also.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the bug that was fixed in SP4 - KB 872843. There are numerous reports on the Internet of people still getting this after installing SP4 - so I don't believe it was fixed properly. You're only recourse seems to be to call CSS and have them investigate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the error fixed via CSS (this is SQL 2000 after all) set the SQL Agent job to restart every minute so that the replication will restart and try again instead of waiting for you to restart it.

If you do this you should have it email you when it fails so that if it starts happening more often you can work with CSS to resolve or upgrade to a newer version of SQL Server.